# Fix image to position on top of another image (responsive)?

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to fix an image of a pin (PNG) to a position on a map. I have been able to properly fix the pin along the x-axis but I am having issues with the pin moving along the Y-axis when the window resizes.

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish. In this example I want to make sure the pin always stays on `MO`. But the `bottom: 45%` is causing the image to move  along the Y-axis when the window is resized.

```css
#img1 {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#img2 {
  width: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 48%;
  bottom: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="img1" src="http://americandreamreschool.com/map/Help/assets/images/simple.png">
  <img id="img2" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/149/149440.png" >
</div>
```

How can I make sure the image stays at the same Y-axis relative to the other image when the window is resized?

Any help appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: can you make sure the image is shown fine here?

Comment: by the way position:relative to should go to the div element, i guess this will fix your issue

Comment: Sorry about the HTTP link. Awesome, that worked. Thank You!! I'm still scratching my head at what is going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position the marker absolute but it should be in relation to the parent `div`

Then adjust your marker percentages accordingly.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

#img1 {
width:100%;
}

#img2 {
  width: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  left:52%;
  top:37%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="img1" src="http://americandreamreschool.com/map/Help/assets/images/simple.png">
  <img id="img2" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/149/149440.png" >
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/qYMBGL)

[**Similar Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dgcha)